# Read and Write to Share point List

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am using asp.net C# 4.0 as may server side script and jquery as my client side script.
Our client provided us a SharePoint URL (aspx) to access. SharePoint machine different from my web application server. They want us to read/write to its SharePoint list.

Is there any way I can do the requirement using the current setup(remote access) without installing any on the SharePoint machine? Our client doesn't want to install or do anything on the SharePoint machine.

Sorry for duplicate question

Here some additional information.

1. I am using jquery 1.9.1
2. I need to perform read/write from the browser.
3. Using Sharepoint 2013

Comment: Since you have question about 2007 this duplicate should be good starting point. As Erik Noren pointed out newer versions have nice client object model, but older web services are accessible from C# just fine. I'd recommend searching first before asking question - you are missing a lot of details for that question to be non-duplicate (i.e. you've mentioned JQuery, but not saying if you need access from browser, missing version in the post, and no code you've tried and have problem with).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of SharePoint, you can use the Client Object Model or SPServices. For a lot of our responsive design work, [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) has been very easy to use.

Comment: Ah. I see. Forgot to ask what version their using. 

Wow. SPServices is great. Thanks for the link. I hope its free.
Also they do suppont lower sharepoint versions like 2007.